Uneven layers - Anycubic Kobra 1
I have this case uneven defect on print when using Anycubic Kobra, it occurs from the first layer. I use 0.6 nozzle and all the default features.
Here're the actions that I already tried:

Built-in auto probing function
=> No improvement
Manual levelling the X Axis
=> No improvement

So I have this question: what is the working principle of auto levelling function in Kobra since it seems like it make no difference at all.
In the past, I used auto levelling before with BLTouch with my previous printer with octoprint and it does make a difference. It applied a new mesh everytime using the levelling.
I don't know it applies the same in Kobra.
Please help to advise if you also experience the same case.


Sorry for the late response. You are correct. It was under extruding, it has a serious problem with the flow, I used the extruded step for 0.4 nozzle. I recalibrated the extruded step and know it is good to go. Thanks a lot for your help, very appreciate it!

It looks as if it hasn't been sliced for a 0.6 mm nozzle. You are seriously under extruding, that is your problem. You clearly see that the second to last layer is visible through the top layer. Please check your slicer and adjust for the extrusion width, or choose a correct nozzle profile, this depends on your slicer.
While we are at the subject, increasing the nozzle size while keeping printing speeds constant, could cause the volumetric flow to increase to a value your hotend is capable of delivering; you may want to lower the printing speed for the 0.6 mm nozzle. You should definitely test if your hotend is capable of pushing out the requested flow.
